# Flink: enrich a data set with a new column based on some computation

Tags: count, dataset, apache-flink

I am trying to do a simple processing with a data set.

Consider a data set with two columns of type `String`. To this data set I want to add a third column of type `Long`, which accumulates the number of records so far seen in the data set.

Example:

Input:

a,b

b,c

c,d

Output:

a,b,1

b,c,2

c,d,3

I have tried the following solution but I get a strange result:

```
    DataSet<Tuple2<String, String>> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("src/main/resources/data_file")
            .ignoreFirstLine()
            .includeFields("11")
            .types(String.class,String.class);

    long cnt=0;
    DataSet<Tuple3<String, String, Long>> csvOut2 = csvInput.map(new MyMapFunction(cnt));


private static class MyMapFunction implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple3<String, String, Long>> {

    long cnt;
    public MyMappingFunction(long cnt) {
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple3<String, String, Long> map(Tuple2<String, String> m) throws Exception {

        Tuple3 <String ,String, Long> resultTuple = new Tuple3(m.f0,m.f1, Long.valueOf(cnt));

        cnt++;
        return resultTuple;
    }
}
```

When I apply this solution for a file with 100 entries I get a count of 47 instead of 100. The counter is restarted at 53. Similarly, when I apply it for even a larger file the counter is somehow reset from time to time so I don't get the total number of the lines.

Could you please explain why is my implementation behaving in this way? Also, what could be a possible solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a multithreading issue. How many tasks slots do you have?

I had to clean up your code before running it - I suggest posting full working examples in future so that you have a chance of getting more answers.

The way you are keeping track of the count is not thread-safe, and so if you have more than one task slot you will have problems with the count value being inaccurate.

The proper way to count, as shown in the data artisans word count example, would be to use the 3rd slot in your tuple to simply store the value 1, and then sum the dataset.

```
resultTuple = new Tuple3(m.f0,m.f1, 1L);
```

then

```
csvOut2.sum(2).print();
```

where 2 is the index of the tuple containing the value 1.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a local/standalone deployment of flink with 1 task slot (that I see in the Job manager GUI). I have thought that it may be a threading issue so I have tried also with an `AtomicLong`. Also, counting the tuples is straightforward. I can do that currently. My problem is adding a column, at the end of each row with the current count.

Comment: Sorry I misread before. Probably you need to use state, as the value depends on what was processed before. Or maybe you could use accumulators http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/dataSet/2-slides.html

Comment: Actually, accumulator is not appropriate here.

Comment: Indeed, I need some way to keep state when processing each record since the current record depends on every record before it.

Comment: state is only available on keyed streams